# Get selected element's in dynamic way

Tags: jquery

In a situation where I have something like this code:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.color_select', function() {
    var id = $(this).val(); //get the current value's option
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
     url: "functions/getSize.php",
        data:{'id':id},
        success:function(data){
            
              var size = $(".size_select");
            
            $(".size_select").html(data); // i need to define this with a dynamic way

        }
    });
});
```

Is there any way to define  `$(".size_select").html(data);` in dynamic way like this

```
$(document).on('change', '.color_select', function() {
var id = $(this).val(); //get the current value's option
```

????

Comment: What is `.size_select`?

Comment: what does `data` look like?  is it JSON?  html?

Comment: `<select name="name" class="form-control color_select" required>`
  `<select name="name" class="form-control size_select" required>`

Comment: the data is html 

`<?php
include("../includes/db.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo '<option selected disabled value="">تحديد المقاس</option>';
if(isset($id)){
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM patron_sizes WHERE color_id='$id'");
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['size_count'].'">'.$row['size_name'].'</option>';
}
}`

Comment: If that's the actual value of `data` after that Ajax call comes back, it's going to be a problem.  You need html, not php.

Comment: yes the data is html 

@mr-rogers    the php is to retrieve variable data from Database

`<option value="'.$row['size_count'].'">'.$row['size_name'].'</option>`

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869182/how-to-get-a-select-box-value-and-make-this-value-unique

Comment: Right - but when it gets back to the browser, it needs to be html.  You need the server to evaluate $row['size_count'] etc before it come back to the javascript.  If you get that figured out, the rest of your code should work as expected.  When you inject that php/html into the browser with `$('.select').html(...)`, the php will *not* re-evaluate the injected code.

Comment: @mrrogers Got it , is there any idea to solve it ?

simply the 2 selected elements is repeated based on a variable number 

every one have a deferent options , and the options of the second select box changed when the user select another option from the first select box

the code getting the data , but when the user choose to two select boxes and select the options for the first one then go to the second one to select their custom options , the first one also changed

maybe this video help to understand me

https://youtu.be/-fSASgZcMTw

Comment: What do you mean by "with a dynamic way"? Are there multiple `.size_select` elements, and you need the one next to the `.color_select` that triggered the AJAX request?

Comment: @Barmar exactly that is what I need  ,
this video can explain 
youtu.be/-fSASgZcMTw

Comment: Use DOM traversal relative to `$(this)` to find the related `.size_select`. But also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: how can i use `$(this)` in this case

` $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
     url: "functions/getSize.php",
        data:{'id':id},
        success:function(data){
   
     $mainContEl = $(this).parents('div.sizetickets-fields'),
      $size = $mainContEl.children().find("input.size_select"),
   
            $(".size_select").html(data); // i need to define this with a dynamic way

        }
    });`